# SQL Server : split and loop

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to run a SELECT statement that will show me all possible outputs for a product code.

Currently I have two columns for each product, `ID` (int) and `colourcode` (varchar). For product ID = 1 colourcode = 10,20,30

My desired result is:

```
110
120
130
```

I have created a split function which works fine but in my query I get the error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

My query is:

```
Select 
    p.ID, 
    (select items 
     from dbo.Split(pv.ColorSKUModifiers, ',')) 
from 
    product p 
join 
    ProductVariant pv on (pv.ProductID = p.ProductID)
```

Can anyone help? Ideally I would like ID and items concatenated but that was looking harder to do as I was getting error: Cannot resolve collation conflict for column 1 in SELECT statement.

Comment: Post in sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to get the Cartesian product of two tables. If you have tableA(A) and tableB(B), then the syntax is

```
select tableA.A, tableB.B 
from tableA
     cross join tableB
```

In your case, something like

```
Select product.ID, variants.items
from 
    product cross join
    (select dbo.Split(pv.ColorSKUModifiers,',') as items from productVariant pv )  variants
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that `dbo.Split` is table-valued function. In this case you should use `cross apply` operator:

```
select p.ID, s.items as ColCode
from product p
    join ProductVariant pv on pv.ProductID = p.ProductID
    cross apply dbo.Split(pv.ColorSKUModifiers, ',') s
```

or if you need to concatenate ID and color codes:

```
select cast(p.ID as varchar(20)) + s.items
from product p
    join ProductVariant pv on pv.ProductID = p.ProductID
    cross apply dbo.Split(pv.ColorSKUModifiers, ',') s
```